# Spring Security patterns with regular expressions

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I need to intercept an url with the following pattern:

`<intercept-url pattern="empresas/?/*" ...`

where '?' is an integer e.g. empresas/5/*, empresas/1/**, etc

How can I write the pattern in order to intercept this kinds of URL?

Comment: You are asking for a regex? Did you try "\d+" which is one or more digits?

Comment: Here is my code:     
`
 <http auto-config="true">
  <intercept-url pattern="/empresas/\d+/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
 </http>`

but I think that we must tell spring security that "\d+" is a regex. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `request-matcher` attribute on the surrounding `http` element to `regex` to tell Spring that you want to use regular expression syntax in the `pattern` attributes, see e.g. http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#nsa-http-attributes.